# Pivoting columns based on a key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis, bids

I have the following table:

```
key_column INT,
column_type_id INT, --has only 3 values, e.g. 1,2,3
value INT
```

I want to transfer the datat from that table into my DW fact table which looks like this:

```
key_column INT,
column_type_id INT,
column_type_1 INT,
column_type_2 INT,
column_type_3 INT
```

The matching criteria are as follows:

1) match columns using key_column
2) use column_type_id to determine to which column value should be inserted (if column_type_id = 1 then insert value to column_type_1, etc. after that discard column_type_id and don't make duplicate rows so key_column is distinct)
.

Does anyone have any idea how to do it by either TSQL or (preferably) SSIS?
I should also mention sorting for either merge or duplicate elimination is not an option, because my hardware is too weak to handle sorting of the amount of data I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can execute `INSERT INTO...SELECT` to insert the pivoted data from your original table,

```
INSERT INTO DWFACT( key_column, 
                    column_type_id, 
                    column_type_1, 
                    column_type_2, 
                    column_type_3
                    )
SELECT  key_column, ColTypeID, [1], [2], [3]
FROM    
        (
            SELECT  key_column, 
                    column_type_id as ColTypeID, 
                    column_type_id, 
                    value
            FROM    TableName
        ) org
        PIVOT
        (
            MAX(value)
            FOR column_type_id IN ([1], [2], [3])
        ) pvt
ORDER   BY key_column
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b9348/1)

Comment: After removing the coltypeid the query did the job perfectly, thanks for the help :)